# package randomwalk clashes with [frenchb]{babel}

Tags: expl3, randomwalk

Package `randomwalk` works as expected, except if `\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}` is invoked. Regardless of whether `\RandomWalk` is called or not, compilation ERROR: `! File ended while scanning use of \@for` occurs. I tried fiddling with `\shorthandoff/on{@}` as a similar problem I had in the past with `frenchb` (which involved the `;` character) was fixed with `\shorthandoff{;} ... \shorthandon{;}`, but to no avail.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 17 March 2017
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{randomwalk}
\begin{document}
\verb+\RandomWalk {number = 5000, length = {2pt, 8pt}}+\\
\RandomWalk {number = 1000, length = {2pt, 8pt}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`randomwalk` loads the `lcg` package with `\AtBeginDocument`. As you are loading `babel` before `randomwalk` this means that the colon is already active and so code inside `lcg` breaks.

Imho it would be better if `\randomwalk` would use `etoolbox` and `\AtEndPreamble` or even better simply load `lcg` without options and use `\reinitrand` to setup the needed settings. Inform the author.

You can get around the problem by loading randomwalk ealier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{randomwalk}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\begin{document}
\RandomWalk {number = 1000, length = {2pt, 8pt}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: hmm I was going to post similar but allocate the blame differently:-) I'm not sure it's reasonable to ask every package author to use a non-standard hook, babel probably ought to make its changes later or adjust package loading so that catcodes are normalised

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: But is it reasonable if packages are loaded in \AtBeginDocument? (I don't understand anyway why randomwalk delays the loading so much). And where can babel safely activate the chars?

Comment: babel is (still) in required, it could add to \document directly, leaving the hook for people to safely hook into.  or if it arranged that package loading normalised the catcodes it could turn on shortrefs immediately, which would be less confusing, probably.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes babel could improve a bit here. But randomwalk does it wrong imho too. It should simply load the lcg package and then initialize its counter with `\reinitrand`. Beside the problem with babel the current code only leads to option clashes.

Comment: @David Carlisle @Ulrike Fischer: I am impressed! Happy to make do with the fix of loading `randomwalk` before `frenchb`.  The finer points of the implementation of `randomwalk` aside, I find Bruno Le Floch's package a wonderful example of `expl3` coding, one that has opened up surprising aspects and possibilities of `expl3` I could never have dreamed of. Wish I had stumbled over `randomwalk` 2 years ago. Apologies for waxing lyrical!

Comment: Sorry: I accidentally downvoted this answer… :( I wanted to upvote but now I can't revert the vote unless the answer is edited…

Comment: @clemens: I edited the answer